# Wordpress multiple IIS bindings

Tags: wordpress, iis, binding, dns

I have 2 domains, www.mydomain.co.uk and www.mydomain.com and 4 bindings in IIS 8.5 as follows;

```
www.mydomain.co.uk
mydomain.co.uk
www.mydomain.com
mydomain.com
```

I'm not sure how wordpress is handling this when it's setting is for www.mydomain.co.uk

I think maybe I should redirect the domains rather than bindings within a dingle domain, but am not sure.

Comment: IIS site bindings only control which incoming traffic is allowed to reach that site, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background About how WordPress handles such afterwards, its documentation is your primary source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lex says that, the IIS site bindings will just handle the incoming traffic which comes to the site, it will not affect any site build-in feature.

If your site has multiple site bindings in the IIS that means if IIS find the request wants to access the "www.mydomain.co.uk", it will check the binding list and use the right web site to handle the request and return the right response.

As far as I know, the WordPress will not check the domain, it just works for handle the request and return the right response.

So  there is no need to modify the domain binding, if you wants to allow user to use multiple domain to access your WordPress site.